# Use enter in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing for creating a list of number from input and get the average of the list. The requirement is: when the user enters a number, the number will be appended to the list; when the user press `Enter`, the input section will stop and conduct and calculation section.
Here is my code:

```
n = (input("please input a number"))
numlist = []

while n != '':
    numlist.append(float(n))
    n = float(input("please input a number"))

    N = 0
    Sum = 0
    for c in numlist:
        N = N+1
        Sum = Sum+c

Ave = Sum/N
print("there are",N,"numbers","the average is",Ave)
```

if I enter numbers, everything works fine. But when I press `Enter`, it shows `ValueError`. I know the problem is with `float()`. How can I solve this?

Comment: The first `n` is still a string.

Comment: During the append in while loop, the first n is converted to float in numlist.append(). I just removed the float conversion for the second n and it worked.

Comment: When you press Enter then input cannot be converted to float and it correctly shows value error. You can save input result and check it before trying to convert it to float or you can use try/catch block to catch the exception and calculate the average. Other than that I cannot even begin to count how many issues you have in such a small code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `float()` around the `input()` function inside your loop because you call `float()` when you append `n` to `numlist`.

Answer (score -1):

this should solve ur prob ,by adding a try,catch block around ur print statement

```
n = (input("please input a number"))
numlist = []

while True :
    numlist.append(float(n))
    #####cath the exception and break out of 
    try :
        n = float(input("please input a number"))
    except ValueError :
        break


N = 0
Sum = 0
for c in numlist:
    N = N+1
    Sum = Sum+c



Ave = Sum/N
print("there are",N,"numbers","the average is",Ave)
```

Comment: Why unnecessarily call `float()` twice?